# logstash geoip parsing using apache_log data failed

Tags: filter, logstash, geoip

I am new to Elasticsearch..

I want to use apache_logs data to use geoip filter in logstash.

apache log data:

`"83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:03 +0000] \"GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/kibana-search.png HTTP/1.1\" 200 203023 \"http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36\""`

logstash.conf

```
    input {
        tcp {
            port => 9900
        }
    }

    filter {
        grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{IP:clientip}" }
        }

        geoip {
            source => "clientip"
        }
    }

    output {
        stdout { }
    }
```

and i got an error below..

```
Pipeline error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: GeoIP Filter in ECS-Compatiblity mode requires a `target` when `source` is not an `ip` sub-field, eg. [client][ip]> 
....
Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Reload<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
```

here is my data output:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2022-03-09T09:40:28.652491Z,
      "clientip" => "83.149.9.216",
      "@version" => "1",
       "message" => "83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:03 +0000] \"GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/kibana-search.png HTTP/1.1\" 200 203023 \"http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36\"",
         "event" => {
        "original" => "83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:03 +0000] \"GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/kibana-search.png HTTP/1.1\" 200 203023 \"http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36\""
    }
}
```

Could you guys help me to solve this problem?? Thanks.

Comment: Which Logstash version are you using? It is complaining about [ecs compatibility](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/ecs-ls.html), are you using version 8?

You should define a `target` field with `target => fieldname`, or set the ecs compatibility to false on that plugin with `ecs_compatibility => disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

i change config like bewlow:

```
geoip {
    source => "[ip]"
    ecs_compatibility => disabled
}
```

may this help

Answer (score 0):

You can this change below:

```html
  geoip {
        source => "[clientip]"
        ecs_compatibility => disabled
   }
```